# Extracting part of a string surrounded by signs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that will print part of a string if a certain pattern is found inside that string.

I have an array of string that contains the following:

```
pages =  ["|stackoverflow.com| The website serves as a platform for users to ask and answer questions." , "|reddit.com| A social news aggregation, web content rating, and discussion website"]
```

When the user enter `urlReturn(pages,"platform")`, the function should output `stackoverflow.com`

I have tried but to no avail, help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why "stackoverflow.com" and not "reddit.com"?

Comment: Because the string "platform" appears in the string where "stackoverflow.com" is held, not where "reddit.com" is held

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlReturn = (pages, text) => pages.filter(page => page.indexOf(text) > -1).map(page => /\|([^|]*)\|/.exec(page)[1])
```

I suggest you look up these things in MDN. There are several good articles/documention there about regular expression and collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (idx in pages) {
    if (pages[idx].indexOf('platform') != -1) {
        console.log(pages[idx].substr(1, pages[idx].indexOf('|', 1) - 1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet can help you cover multiple results:

```js
pages = ["|stackoverflow.com| The website serves as a platform for users to ask and answer questions.",
  "|reddit.com| A social news aggregation, web content rating, and discussion website",
  "|lorem.com| Some site containing platform",
  "|ipsum.com| Some site containing discussion"
];

// returns the array containing multiple result
function urlReturn(pages, query) {
  var result = []
  pages.forEach(function(page) {
    var match = (new RegExp('^\\|(.+?)\\|.*' + query + '.*', 'g')).exec(page);
    if (match !== null) {
      result.push(match[1]);
    }
  });

  return (result);
}

console.log(urlReturn(pages, "platform"));
// ["stackoverflow.com", "lorem.com"]

console.log(urlReturn(pages, "discussion"));
// ["reddit.com", "ipsum.com"]

console.log(urlReturn(pages, "rating"));
// ["reddit.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution to the function you ask for:

```
function urlReturn(pages, query) {
  for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    if (pages[i].indexOf(query) > 0) {
      return pages[i].split("|")[1]; 
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

This function searches the the pages array until it finds an index containing the `query` argument, then uses the string `"|"` as a delimiter to split the value at the index into another array and return the second index of this array, `[1]`, which contains the substring you are seeking. If no match, returns an empty string.

Checking that it works:

```js
function urlReturn(pages, query) {
  for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    if (pages[i].indexOf(query) > 0) {
      return pages[i].split("|")[1]; 
    }
  }
  return '';
}

var pages = [
  "|stackoverflow.com| The website serves as a platform for users to ask and answer questions." , 
  "|reddit.com| A social news aggregation, web content rating, and discussion website"
];

console.log(urlReturn(pages, "platform"));
```